# Query to find order products for related accounts in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

On the Accounts form, I want to be able to show all Order Products for that Account and any related Account. My aim is to give the user an easy way to see what has been bought by a customer with several related offices (Accounts).
Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: AFAIK this can only be achieved through unsupported tweaks of the fetchxml of the subgrid itself. I also highly doubt this kind of visualization is going to be useful at all because only a handful of rows can be seen at a time. A report might be the only way to provide this kind of visualization in a useful fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with a plugin.  The general steps would be:

1. Ensure the view that is used on the order product subgrid on the Account form is not used anywhere else.
2. Make a unique change to the view columns or filter criteria that will let you distinguish it from other views.  For example, you could add a condition of "createdon contains data", which most likely would not be used anywhere else
3. Create a pre-RetrieveMultiple plugin on Order Product.
4. In the plugin, get the query from the input parameters and check for the "createdon contains data" condition.  If it does not exist, exit the plugin.
5. If the condition exists, this is the view you want to update.  In the query, find the condition that has accountid.
6. Use the accountid to retrieve related child and parent accounts.
7. Update the query with a condition checking if accountid is in the list of all the accountids you retrieved.
8. The query should now return all the relevant order products and display them on the Account form.

This is a rather involved solution with only the high level steps outlined here.

Here is a link that shows an example of modifying a query in a pre-retrievemultple plugin:
https://hachecrm2011.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/filtering-views-by-intercepting-retrieve-multiple-queries-with-a-plugin/